# Why does appending to a list take forever?

Tags: python, list, python-os

I wrote the following code:

```
import fnmatch
ll = []
for items in src:
    for file in os.listdir('/Users/swaghccc/Downloads/PulledImages/'):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, items.split('/')[-1]):
            print file
            ll.append(file)
```

my `src` list contains paths to images.
something like:

```
/path/to/image.jpg
```

These images are a subset of the images contained in the directory `PulledImages`.

The printing of the matched images works correctly.
But when I try to put those imagesnames into a list `ll` it takes forever.

What on earth am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's frankly hard to believe. `print` is a **much** more expensive operation than `list.append()`, by orders of magnitude. Can you provide a self-contained [mcve] which allows others to reproduce your result?

Comment: why fnmatch ?  shouldnt `if items.endswith('/'+file):` suffice? why item**S** ? you do not use any of fnmatch'es features...

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if the OP is trying to avoid appending things more than once? They should be using a data structure that allows O(1) lookups, if so.

Comment: Even if that were true, though, it's not the append that would be slow, but the other code they're using to gate it.

Comment: (and why in the world would you run `os.listdir()` in a loop, rather than running it once and caching its results in a structure you can refer to with an O(1) lookup?)

Answer (score 3):

Appending **doesn't** take forever. Searching through a list, however, takes more time the longer your list is; and `os.listdir()`, being an operating system call, can be unavoidably slow when running against a large directory.

To avoid that, use a dictionary or set, not a list, to track the names you want to compare against -- and build that set only once, outside your loop.

```
# run os.listdir only once, storing results in a set for constant-time lookup
import sets
files = sets.Set(os.listdir('/Users/swaghccc/Downloads/PulledImages/'))

ll = []
for item in src:
    if item.split('/')[-1] in files:
        ll.append(file)
```

<sub>Community Wiki because I don't believe this question to be within topic guidelines without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); thus, not taking rep/credit for this answer.</sub>

Comment: Switching from list to set in my case took the time down from 6 minutes to less than 1 second.